# Error : d.select2 is not a function while using angular-select2.js

Tags: angularjs

So guys I have tried `select.js` for `jquery`, it works fine. Now I am trying `select.js` for `angular` but getting this error:

```
TypeError: d.select2 is not a function
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r23mjL01/1/

Comment: I believe you should add jQuery before angular and select2 library along with the angular directive, you are just missing the actual code and select2 function is not included

Answer (score 1):

You are using Select2 4.0, aren't you?

You should be using the code that is located in this other branch: https://github.com/motin/angular-select2/tree/select2-4.0-support-wip

Check out this issue: https://github.com/rubenv/angular-select2/issues/18

Comment: Is there any updates for this issue, Iam also facing the same issue mentioned in the http://jsfiddle.net/r23mjL01/1/. Iam using select2-v1.4.3